# How to match a string (phrase) to a HashMap values quickly?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I have a HashMap whose key is id and whose value is text:

```
HashMap<String,String> textMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
textMap.put("id_1","She");
textMap.put("id_2","has");
textMap.put("id_3","a"); 
textMap.put("id_4","neck");
textMap.put("id_5","pain");
//.. more elements in textMap
```

I would like to find the related ids given a phrase, like 'neck pain', so in this case the result should be id_4 and id_5.

Can anybody suggest an efficient algorithm to match the phrase with ids?

I'm sorry I forgot to include an important condition. I have both the phrase and the offset of word, like "start_5_end_14", which means that 5 should be the start of "neck" given that the start of "She" is 0. However, what complicates the case is that the offset might not be correct.

Comment: I think you must create second map and key will be name

Answer (score 5):

Maintain a reversed map in which you map the words to the id's. Then, traverse over your phrase and call `reversedTextMap.get(word)` for each `word` in the phrase.

Comment: Actually I may have duplicate content texts so that I cannot reverse the HashMap to use the original values as keys...

Comment: easy and clever ! I love that :)

Comment: You can use a CoupleList so, like I wrote one : https://github.com/nicolas-zozol/robusta-web-library/blob/master/robusta/library/src/main/java/com/robustaweb/library/commons/util/CoupleList.java

Comment: @DanQing So do you mean `textMap` will be many-to-one? If so, how can you know which id to use?

Comment: @A.R.S. It's my fault that I forgot to provide another condition....I just edited my question...

Answer (score 3):

You can use [BiMap](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release09/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html) from Guava libraries

```
BiMap<String,String> textMap  = HashBiMap.create();

    textMap.put("id_1","She");
    textMap.put("id_2","has");
    textMap.put("id_3","a"); 
    textMap.put("id_4","neck");
    textMap.put("id_5","pain");
    BiMap<String,String> idToText = textMap.inverse();

    System.out.println(idToText.get("neck")); 
    System.out.println(idToText.get("pain"));
```

If you have duplicate values  then you can use [MultiMap](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release03/javadoc/index.html?com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html)

Comment: Note that @DanQing mentioned that his map can have duplicate values. In this case a BiMap is not useful. He should use a Multimap.

Comment: @dan Yes you are right. But he has not mentioned in the question. This answer was for the question :)

Comment: I know, I started to suggest the same use of a BiMap :) when I noticed a comment that he is having duplicate values.

Answer (score 1):

Since you can have the same value for multiple keys you can use a [Multimap](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release03/javadoc/index.html?com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) to represent the value to key relation. You will use:

```
Collection<V>   get(K key)
```

To retrieve the list of ids starting from a value.